# Python Operation on closed file

Tags: python

I get the error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file., and i dont understand why...
The error happens everytime, the function is executed in the line: for row in reader: ...

```
def login():

    global logged_in
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Please enter your password: ")

    hash_func = hashlib.sha256()
    encoded_pw = password.encode()
    hash_func.update(encoded_pw)
    password = hash_func.hexdigest()

    with open('accounts.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if username == row['username'] and password == row['password']:
                logged_in = True
                print(f"Welcome {username}!")
                csvfile.close()
                return bool(logged_in)
            print("Username or password incorrect!")
            print("Please try again or create an account.")
            csvfile.close()
```

Also am i using .close() correctly? Do i have to use it twice?

Comment: You don’t have to use .close() at all. Why do you think you should?

Comment: i read it somewhere that you should close files, after opening

Comment: But surely when you read about ‘with open(... ‘ you would have also read that this makes close unnecessary?

Comment: so i need .close() if i only use open(x) ?

Comment: Yes, you open a file, you close it. A context manager makes the closing automatic and exception safe.

Comment: ah okay, i didnt know that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `with` creates a context manager that closes the file for you when that with block ends, so no, you shouldn't do that on your own

Comment: If you *do* decide to unnecessarily call `csvfile.close()`, you should do so *after* the loop, not at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Or with a for-else